# Context microservice throwing error in DXA app

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, microservices, context-engine

I have set up a fresh Web 8.5 install, and a fresh DXA 1.7 Java web app.
However, when I try to start my webapp, I get an error

```
com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientHttpError: Unable to get response from OData service: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><metadata:error xmlns:metadata="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata"><metadata:code>9000</metadata:code><metadata:message>org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException</metadata:message></metadata:error>

com.sdl.odata.client.util.ODataClientUtils.buildException(ODataClientUtils.java:93)
com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:199)
com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.callEndpoint(BasicEndpointCaller.java:82)
com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.getODataResponse(DefaultODataClient.java:141)
com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.getEntity(DefaultODataClient.java:69)
com.sdl.context.odata.client.ODataContextEngineProxy.resolve(ODataContextEngineProxy.java:107)
com.sdl.context.odata.client.CachingContextEngine.resolve(CachingContextEngine.java:61)
com.sdl.context.odata.client.api.ODataContextEngine.resolve(ODataContextEngine.java:46)
com.sdl.webapp.tridion.contextengine.ContextServiceClaimsProvider.getContextClaims(ContextServiceClaimsProvider.java:101)
com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.contextengine.ContextEngineImpl.claims(ContextEngineImpl.java:52)
com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.contextengine.ContextEngineImpl.getClaims(ContextEngineImpl.java:32)
com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.contextengine.ContextEngineImpl.deviceFamily(ContextEngineImpl.java:67)
com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.contextengine.ContextEngineImpl.getDeviceFamily(ContextEngineImpl.java:27)
com.sdl.dxa.DxaSpringInitialization$1.processDeviceFamily(DxaSpringInitialization.java:112)
com.sdl.dxa.DxaSpringInitialization$1.resolveViewName(DxaSpringInitialization.java:94)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1211)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1160)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:286)
```

As this looks like an error with my context microservice, I looked at the logs of this service. The service itself started fine, and showed no errors when loading.

However, upon the first request from DXA, I notice the following error in the context service logs

```
2017-10-05 21:55:40,454 ERROR ODataQueryProcessorImpl - Unexpected Exception when executing query.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1575)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.SpringContentDeliveryKernel.ensureInitialised(SpringContentDeliveryKernel.java:38)
at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.registerKernel(KernelFactory.java:40)
at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.getKernel(KernelFactory.java:27)
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getComponent(StorageManagerFactory.java:70)
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getStorageManager(StorageManagerFactory.java:49)
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:175)
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:149)
at com.sdl.context.api.ContextExpressionServiceImpl.getDAOSafely(ContextExpressionServiceImpl.java:91)
at com.sdl.context.api.ContextExpressionServiceImpl.loadContextExpressions(ContextExpressionServiceImpl.java:37)
at com.sdl.context.engine.SimpleContextEngine.updateVocabulary(SimpleContextEngine.java:257)
at com.sdl.context.engine.SimpleContextEngine.enrichedResolve(SimpleContextEngine.java:274)
at com.sdl.context.engine.SimpleContextEngine.resolve(SimpleContextEngine.java:216)
at com.sdl.context.odata.datalayer.dao.ODataContextMapDao.selectByKeyOperation(ODataContextMapDao.java:152)
at com.sdl.context.odata.datalayer.dao.ODataContextMapDao.executeQueryListResult(ODataContextMapDao.java:132)
at com.sdl.context.odata.datalayer.dao.ODataContextMapDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a7568043.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
at com.sdl.context.odata.datalayer.dao.ODataContextMapDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$21e21606.executeQueryListResult(<generated>)
at com.sdl.context.odata.datalayer.ContextDataSource.executeQueryListResult(ContextDataSource.java:124)
at com.sdl.context.odata.datalayer.ContextDataSourceProvider$1.execute(ContextDataSourceProvider.java:49)
at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataQueryProcessorImpl.query(ODataQueryProcessorImpl.java:94)
at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:38)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:29)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configure(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:60)
at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.initialize(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
... 48 common frames omitted
```

From the error, it looks like it can't seem to initialize the storage configuration. However, I just copied the microservice configuration from the SDL Web Installation directory, and kept all default settings.

Am I missing something in my setup ?

The storage config looks very minimal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="8.5" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
<ConfigRepository CacheEnabled="true" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ClientId="registration" ClientSecret="*****" ConnectionTimeout="10000" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" ServiceUri="${discoveryurl:-http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc}" TokenServiceUrl="${tokenurl:-http://localhost:8082/token.svc}">
    <Roles>
        <Role Name="ContextServiceCapability" Url="${contexturl:-http://localhost:8087/context.svc}"/>
    </Roles>
</ConfigRepository>
```

Small update: the error seems to go away if I disable the `context-expression-module`. However, we're planning on using this module, so just leaving it out isn't an option

Comment: Just rebooted my server, and the error seems to have gone. Very odd...

Comment: Please self answer your question with this information, after a few days you can accept your answer and that will close the question, making it a vallid resource for people encountering the same in the future.

Comment: actually, the error returned about an hour ago, so it's not really solved yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above issue sure for cd_storage_config.xml issue on context service

Here is the working config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="8.5"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
  <Global>

    <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
    </ObjectCache>

    <Storages>
      <StorageBindings>
        <Bundle src="storage_extension_dao_bundle.xml"/>
      </StorageBindings>

      <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" >
        <Pool Type="jdbc" CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5"/>
        <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
          <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost" />
          <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
          <Property Name="databaseName" Value="xxxx" />
          <Property Name="user" Value="xxxx" />
          <Property Name="password" Value="xxxx" />
        </DataSource>
      </Storage>
    </Storages>
  </Global>

  <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="true">
  </ItemTypes>

  <License Location="C:/SDL/licenses/cd_licenses.xml"/>

</Configuration>
```